How to check if someone presses the button early?
I am making a reaction time game with a Raspberry Pi Pico and Micropython using the picozero library. How do I check before the button turns green if someone pressed the button early. My current solution is not working as you would have to rapidly click early for it to detect it
from picozero import RGBLED, Button
import time
import random

rgb = RGBLED(red =18, green =17, blue =16)
button = Button(15)

times = []
index = 0

print("Press the button to start")

while not button.is_pressed:
    time.sleep(0.01)
    
time.sleep(1)

for i in range(5):
    early_finish = True
    print(early_finish)
    index += 1
    rand_num = random.randrange(2, 4)
    
    time.sleep(1)
    
    while not button.is_pressed:       
        rgb.color = (255, 0, 0)
        print("\nWait for the green light...")
        time.sleep(rand_num)
        early_finish = False
        break
       
    if early_finish == False:
        
        rgb.color = (0, 255, 0)
        start_time = time.time_ns()
                    
        while not button.is_pressed:
            time.sleep(0.001)
            
        reaction_time = (time.time_ns() - start_time) / 1000000000
        times.append(reaction_time)
        rgb.color = (255, 0, 0)
        reaction_time = str(reaction_time)
        
        print("Reaction Time: " + reaction_time +"seconds")
        print("\nYour times were: " + str(times))
    else:
        print("Too Early!")       
               
sumOfScores = 0
for i in times:
    sumOfScores += i
    
average = sumOfScores / len(times)

print("Your average reaction time was: " + str(average))

